# Difference between index and path=""

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm now learning React Router. I have the following set of routes:

```typescript
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/books">
        <Route path=":id" element={<Book />} />
        <Route path="new" element={<NewBook />} />
        <Route index element={<BookList />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

If I replace `index` in the last route with `path=""` I see no difference in behavior.

```typescript
{// ...
        <Route path="" element={<BookList />} />
```

**Why should I prefer to use `index`, instead of `path=""`?**

Answer (score 1):

There's no effective difference. The empty path is appended to the parent route; both `index` and `path=""` thus evaluate to the `/books` route.

> Why should I prefer to use `index`, instead of `path=""`?

It's probably best to be explicit, but I don't think the community has evolved to strongly prefer one over the other. The [index routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#index-routes) guide also doesn't delve too deep into the concept other than what it means to be an index route in terms of route matching. IMHO using the `index` prop makes the intent clear and it looks more clean than passing an empty path string.

Comment: I've just tested this (with removing the `:id` route), and `path=""` also only matches `/books` exactly. (I'm using React Router v6.14.2 and `<BrowserRouter />`, if that's relevant.)

Comment: @ZevSpitz Ah, you're correct. I don't think I quite explained the right aspect. I've updated my answer though so hopefully things are a bit better now. Let me know if anything still is unclear.

Comment: _using the `index` prop makes the intent clear and it looks more clean than passing an empty path string_ I would argue it means learning a new API concept (index routes) to do something that can be done without the new concept. It would be another matter if setting `index` actually did something different.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Not to really debate on this, but FWIW `path=""` isn't something the RRD documentation refers to, and conceptually, doesn't make sense, paths should have truthy values. I guess if you *really* wanted the "why" you could create an issue in the RRD repo and ask the maintainers why they introduced an `index` prop that does the same thing as passing an empty path string. RRDv6 was a complete rewrite, and they brought over many remix.run concepts, and if I'm not mistaken, index routes, named after the index.js file that represents them, is a likely catalyst.